# ManyToOne many Posts for one User -> creates new User by creating a Post

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

I am using Symfony and Doctrine.

I have two Entities, User and Pots. 
Every logged User can create as many Post he want to.
Every Post is associated to one User.

Thats the Workflow: I log in with an User, this user create a Post. A New Post is saved in the Database with a foreigkey on the User wo create it.

Problem: when the User create the Post, the post ist create, but a new User is created too. The new Post is asssociate to the new Users and not to the logged User.

USER ENTITY:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;  
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Post;

    /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name= "User")
    */

    class User 
    {
       /** 
          * @ORM\Column(type = "integer") 
          * @ORM\Id
          * @ORM\GeneratedValue("AUTO") 
       */ 
       private $id;  
        /**
            * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 50) 
        */
        private $account;
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 22)
        */
        private $password;
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 100)
        */
        private $email;
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "integer", length = 1)
        */
        private $type;

        /**
        *
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="user")
        */

        private $posts;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set account
         *
         * @param string $account
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setAccount($account)
        {
            $this->account = $account;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get account
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAccount()
        {
            return $this->account;
        }

        /**
         * Set password
         *
         * @param string $password
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get password
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        /**
         * Set mail
         *
         * @param string $mail
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get mail
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * Set type
         *
         * @param integer $type
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setType($type)
        {
            $this->type = $type;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get type
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getType()
        {
            return $this->type;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Add post
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Post $post
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function addPost(\AppBundle\Entity\Post $post)
        {
            $this->posts[] = $post;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove post
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Post $post
         */
        public function removePost(\AppBundle\Entity\Post $post)
        {
            $this->posts->removeElement($post);
        }

        /**
         * Get posts
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getPosts()
        {
            return $this->posts;
        }
    }
```

POST ENTITY:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;  
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use AppBundle\Entity\User;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;



    /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name = "Post")
    * @Vich\Uploadable
    */

    class Post 
    {

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue("AUTO")
        */

        private $id;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 25)
        */
        private $title;
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 255)
        */
        private $text;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type= "string", length = 250)
        */

        private $pic;

        /**
        * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="post_file", fileNameProperty="pic")
        *
        */

        private $picFile;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */

        private $user;



    public function getPicFile(){

        return $this->picFile;

    }

    public function setPicFile(File $picFile = null){

        $this->picFile = $picFile;

        return $this;
    }


        /**
         * Set user
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
         *
         * @return Coach
         */
        public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
        {
            $this->user = $user;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get user
         *
         * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
         */
        public function getUser()
        {
            return $this->user;
        }

        /**
         * Set title
         *
         * @param string $title
         *
         * @return Post
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get title
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        /**
         * Set text
         *
         * @param string $text
         *
         * @return Post
         */
        public function setText($text)
        {
            $this->text = $text;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get text
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getText()
        {
            return $this->text;
        }

        /**
         * Set pic
         *
         * @param string $pic
         *
         * @return Post
         */
        public function setPic($pic)
        {
            $this->pic = $pic;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get pic
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPic()
        {
            return $this->pic;
        }

        /**
         * Set id
         *
         * @param integer $id
         *
         * @return Post
         */
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:
NOTE: Here is take the logged User from the SESSION. This works, i output the id from the User i use and it was the correct id.

```
public function FrameCoachNewAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->start();
        $user = $session->get('user');

        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            $post = $form->getData();       
            $post->setUser($user);

            $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $doct->persist($post);



            $doct->flush();

            //return New Response($post->getUser()->getId());

            return $this->RedirectToRoute('app_frame_coach');
        }else{
            return $this->render('/frame/frame_coach_new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$session = $request->getSession();
        $session->start();
        $user = $session->get('user');` Why don't you `$user = $this->getUser()` it return you the current user connected in your sf application. I don't see an error in your code except this part

Comment: try to move your  cascade={"persist"} on attribute posts of user

Comment: to get user logged you should used $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser() see : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left the Entity like you said, but i changed the Controller to. The Session User Object dind't work to associate it to the Post. So I just toke the ID from the Session and then search the user object again throw that id in the database and used this instade.

```
public function FrameCoachNewAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->start();
    $users = $session->get('user');

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
    $user = $repo->find($users->getId());




    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $post = $form->getData();       
        $post->setUser($user);

        $doct->persist($post);
        $doct->flush();

        //return New Response($post->getUser()->getId());

        return $this->RedirectToRoute('app_frame_coach');
    }else{
        return $this->render('/frame/frame_coach_new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user is the strong side so you should move the cascade={"persist"} option to user, then the user can save the post not the other way. It seems the cascade={"persist"} option is rewriting the setUser method. When you use the cascade={"persist"} option that entity would create the targetEntity.

Comment: i did this changes like you said, but i get this error:      A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Post#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\User@000000004e4d723a0000000027513b66. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\User#__toString()' to get a clue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Juan I. Morales Pestana

```
class User 
{
    // ...


     /**
      *
      * @ORM\OneToMany(
      *    targetEntity="Post", 
      *    mappedBy="user", 
      *    cascade={"persist"}
      *    )
      */ 
      private $posts;

      // ...

     /**
      * Constructor
      */
      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
      }

      /**
       * Add post
       *
       * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Post $post
       *
       * @return User
       */
       public function addPost(\AppBundle\Entity\Post $post)
       {
           $this->posts[] = $post;

           $post->setUser($this);

           return $this;
       }
```

Comment: STILL GETTING THE SAME ERROR     A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Post#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\User@0000000073015acf0000000046a06425. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\User#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: Try to clean the database and update the schema from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it not using the Session object. See anser above.